# Trying to just get the Day, Year and Month from angular material DatePicker

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I was trying to get just the `mm/dd/yyyy`, I tried using `Date.getFullYear()` and other methods but it is not working in Angular.

```
<form class="example-container" 
            #employeeForms="ngForm" 
            (submit)="submit(employeeForms)">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Due Date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```
console.log(data.value.date) // Wed Oct 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to format your date to "DD/MM/YYYY" format

```
moment(data.value.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

and i don't know why use data.value.date as you used ngModel 'date' you could have called

```
moment(this.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```